# Nothing happens when I push my repositories from my mac to Github

Tags: git

I tried to push my repositories from my Mac to GitHub but it's not uploading. Each time I try to push, I am asked for credentials which I input, but nothing [happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0MNu.png)

Comment: For security reasons, GitHub deprecated the username and password authentication. Have you created ssh key or access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a personal access tokens instead of your GitHub password. You can create an access token [here](https://github.com/settings/tokens). Also your local git repository has to be connected to your remote one in GitHub. Resource [here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps if still not fixed yet:

1. check you local branch name and remote[github.com's branch name, cause you have to check the update in the same branch you pushed, not the default one]
2. generate an access token as suggested in `Petar's` answer and use that token. Github doesn't support direct password submission any more[I faced this issue]
3. Also, make sure you have added your remote repository in your local. To check that, use `git remote -v`. If you don't see your github repo link applying this, add your origin applying: `git remote add origin` command. Then push it to your desired branch.

Comment: I used token and it worked. thanks